# In Dafny, can the relationship between integer/natural division and real division be proved?

Tags: integer-division, dafny

I would like to prove this:

```
lemma NatDivision(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires b != 0
  ensures a / b == (a as real / b as real).Floor
```

I don't know where to start—this seems almost axiomatic.

If I knew what the axioms *were*, I could work from there, but I poked around in the Dafny source code and couldn't find axioms for `nat` division. (*This Is Boogie 2* claims Boogie requires you to define your own, so I imagine they're there somewhere, maybe in C# code.)

(The broader context: I'm trying to prove that `(a + n * b) % b == a % b` for natural numbers, using [this approach](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/modcyc.html). Here's the [almost-working Dafny proof](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/OEpG).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done in three lines:

```
lemma NatDivision(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires b != 0
  ensures a / b == (a as real / b as real).Floor
{
  // A basic fact about the natural division and modulo operations:
  assert a == (a / b) * b + (a % b);

  // Cast some values to `real`, because this is a programming language.
  // (In math, 7 and 7.0 are the same object and this wouldn't be needed...)
  assert a as real == (a / b) as real * b as real + (a % b) as real;

  // Divide through by b.
  assert a as real / b as real == (a / b) as real + (a % b) as real / b as real;

  // Aha! That reveals that the real quotient `a as real / b as real` is equal
  // to the natural quotient `a / b` (a natural number) plus a fraction.
  // This looks enough like `Floor` that Dafny can take it from here.
}
```

I still haven't found the axioms for division.

**How I found this proof:** First, I assumed that Dafny does *not* define either natural division or real division in terms of the other.  So then how are they defined? I wrote down my best guesses:

```
// natural division
    a / b == the unique number q | a == q * b + r, 0 <= r < b.

// real division
    a / b == the unique number q | q * b == a
```

From there it was a simple matter of trying every possible dead end that can be derived from these two facts before stumbling upon the trick above.

I had a hunch the proof would hinge on something in each definition that did not hold for the other. Sure enough, the first definition became the first assertion of the proof, and the remainder term was important. The second definition is not used directly, but if you look closely you can see a spot where we assume that real multiplication `* b as real` cancels out real division `/ b as real`.

Answer (score 2):

Jason's own answer is great! I'll just add one note about the axioms of division.

Unfortunately, there's no easy place in Dafny's source code to look for these axioms, because they are built in to the underlying solver Z3. You might be able to find some useful things by reading about the theories of nonlinear integer/real arithmetic [here](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories.shtml). But things are a bit complicated by the fact that these documents often define things very abstractly, by reference to "the mathematical definition" instead of spelling things out.

That said, perhaps a more useful resource would be to see how others have historically dealt with nonlinear (mostly integer) arithmetic in Dafny. For that, I recommend reading the math library developed as part of the IronFleet project [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Ironclad/tree/master/ironfleet/src/Dafny/Libraries/Math). (Start by reading the files whose names contain the word "nonlinear"; those are the lowest-level proofs that are closest to the axioms.)

Comment: Those IronFleet modules are a fantastic resource.